# how to filter issues on gitlab similar to github

Tags: github, gitlab

Github has a clear issue query language detailed [here](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/). For example if I wanted to see all issues created in September-October 2016 that have a `DEV-OPS` label on it.. I would simply put

```
is:issue is:open created:=>2016-09-01 created:<2016-10-01 label:dev-ops
```

in the search query.. Is there a way to do this on gitlab?

Comment: In the meantime: https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/22/gitlab-11-2-released/#search-labels-in-project-labels-list

Answer (score 0):

GitLab does not have this feature currently, but it's planned for the upcoming 8.14 release. You may follow the issue here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21747

Answer (score 0):

GitLab 12.6 (December 2019) makes it possible to [filter issues and merge requests by release](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2019/12/22/gitlab-12-6-released/): [issue 32632](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/32632).

> As a user, I want to be able to filter issues and merge requests by release, so that I can have a better overview of the items associated to a release (over one or more milestones).

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/#issues-and-merge-requests-per-project)

For example, filtering by `Author = Jane` and `Milestone != 12.6` filters for the issues where Jane is the author and the milestone is not 12.6.

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/img/issue_search_filter_v12_7.png]